# Geoserver 2.22-RC Compatible Community Extensions

Tags: docker, geoserver

I am working with a Geoserver Docker Image from their main repo https://github.com/geoserver/docker.

Anyone know, what is the compatible GSR Community Extension version for the Geoserver 2.22-RC version?

I tried both geoserver-2.23-SNAPSHOT-gsr-plugin and geoserver-2.23-SNAPSHOT-gsr-plugin but none of them seemed to be registered. I don't see them listed under **Server Status**

[image]

Also when I go to the rest url, I don't see anything under rest url of the workspace either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the download page you can always get to the archived versions (on the right) if for
some reason you don't want to use a supported version.

[image]

However for community modules we only build them for the current snapshot.  They can always be found on the [build server](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/). So, I would recommend moving to the 2.22.0 and hoping that the snapshot build will work or compiling it yourself. Of course if it's working is vital to your business then you should seek [commercial support](https://geoserver.org/support/) to move it to supported.

Comment: Thank you Ian. I was looking for 2.22.0 but unfortunately this docker image is not available yet. It fails.


FROM docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.22.0 as build


So I figured I could use Release Candidate (RC) one. So should we be using a Stable Version always instead of Snapshot or RC ?